# jQuery - Find and remove multiple attributes of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, attributes

I am trying to find all divs with class "comment-like" that also has "data-id" attributes equals to 118603,1234,1234,118601,118597 and if some div contains one of these data value, then remove that data attribute.

So far I created this, but it is not working currently.

```
remove_comments = 118603,1234,1234,118601,118597;
$('.comment-like').find('[data-id="' + remove_comments + '"]').removeAttr('data-id');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically create a query string to capture all the divs you are looking for. The query string would look like this:

```
.comment-like[data-id="118603"], .comment-like[data-id="1234"], etc...
```

```js
var ids = [118603, 1234, 1234, 118601, 118597];
var queryString = ids
  .map(function(id) {
    return '.comment-like[data-id="' + id + '"]';
  })
  .join(', ');

$(queryString).each(function(i, el) {
  $(el).removeAttr('data-id');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment-like" data-id="118603"></div>
<div class="comment-like" data-id="1234"></div>
<div class="comment-like" data-id="0"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution is just loop through your ids

```
remove_comments = 118603,1234,1234,118601,118597;
rc = remove_comments.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < rc.length; i++) {
  $('.comment-like').find('[data-id="' + rc[i] + '"]').removeAttr('data-id'); 
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you can define multiple values to a variable without being array or string. remove_comments in console will only return 118603.

Answer (score -1):

If you open the developer console in Chrome and typ this in:

`remove_comments = 118603,1234,1234,118601,118597;`

`remove_comments`

You can see what is actually happening.

One approach that should work is to put it in an array, and then loop over it:

```
var remove_comments = [118603,1234,1234,118601,118597];
for (var i = 0; i < remove_comments.length; i++) {
    $('.comment-like').find('[data-id="' + remove_comments[i] + '"]').removeAttr('data-id'); 
}
```